# Why can't I convert a string from an entry widget to float?

Tags: python, string, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to build a simple program using tkinter and I want to assign the value that the user enters into an entry widget as a float variable, not a string.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

x_entry = Entry(root)
x_entry.pack()
x_string=x_entry.get()

def enter_click(event):
    x=float(x_string)
    print(x)

enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter")
enter_button.pack()
enter_button.bind("<Button-1>", enter_click)
enter_button.bind("<Return>", enter_click)

root.mainloop()
```

For some reason, Python keeps giving me the following error, saying that it couldn't convert the string to float, even when I enter simple numbers:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/isstudio/Desktop/example.py", line 10, in enter_click
    x=float(x_string)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: It sure looks to me like `x_string` will always be empty. `float("")` gives me exactly the error you're getting. I suggest extracting the string value from the `Entry` in your event handler, rather than during setup, though even then you may need to do some checking to make sure it's an acceptable value (e.g. if the user types `blah` instead of `3.13`, don't crash).

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a perfect sense now. I will make sure to give an exception for strings that are not convertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify to:

```
from Tkinter import *


def enter_click(event):
    x=float(x_entry.get())
    print(x)

root = Tk()

x_entry = Entry(root)
x_entry.pack()


enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter")
enter_button.pack()
enter_button.bind("<Button-1>", enter_click)
enter_button.bind("<Return>", enter_click)

root.mainloop()
```

You want to read the string from the window in the click event, therefore the line `x_string=x_entry.get()` remains effectless, unless within the function `enter_click(event)`. Therefore I replaced `x=float(x_string)` by `x=float(x_entry.get())` and removed `x_string=x_entry.get()`. That was all.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what you did, so the reader doesn't have to go line-by-line looking for differences.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I did this yesterday night 3am and couldn't think straight. Sorry about that.